# TFVC $tf folder recreated after source control in converted to GIT

Tags: git, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, tfs, tfvc

Everything in my VS2015 project was checked in a TFVC (Team Foundation Version Control) repository in TFS. The project is later checked into another GIT repository in the same TFS server.  When I check out from the new GIT repository, a hidden $tf is created even no files are changed.  This prevents me from switching to another branch.  I manually deleted tfs, bin, obj, packages folders on the TFS repository. With Visual Studio 2015 Team Explore, I did a fresh clone to a new workspace folder. I added a .gitignore file with \bin, \obj, $tf in it.  The Team Explorer still lists changes in those folders even nothing is changed.  I deleted the original workspace folder, but it gets recreated every time.  The Does anyone know what is going on?  Thanks.

Comment: "Did a fresh clone to a new workspace folder" - did you clone to a completely clean folder? or to a folder that is mapped in TFVC? Can you make sure that you clone to a completely new folder that is not associated with TFVC?

Does this only get added if you clone via Visual Studio? If you clone via the command line, is the repository on disk created without the $tf folders?

Comment: I delete everything in the old workspace and recloned it into the same workspace folder. Yes, the $tf folder is gone after I cloned to a different workspace folder, but old folder still comes back after deletion in a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would bet that you still have a workspace mapped to the same folder for TFVC. Delete the workspace either via Visual Studio itself or with the `tf workspace` command.

Comment: I could not find the tf command on my workstation.  Do I need to install the command line tool?

Comment: To launch the Visual Studio command prompt, from Windows Start, choose Visual Studio 2015, then choose the the Developer Command Prompt for V2015 shortcut: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands

Comment: You can also remove workspaces via Source Control Explorer in Visual Studio. The following link has some details: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/create-work-workspaces